# How can I find the external source of a dynamically generated string in php?

Tags: php, string, komodo, navicat

I am modifying php code that I did not write. I'm working on a LAMP stack.

I have searched the entire site (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) in Komodo and entering the string I am searching for. I am aware of two databases being used to store *most* of the content. I have searched all tables in Navicat and found several instances of the string.

However, there is one last instance of that string on the site. It's not in the site folder. It's not in the database. Is there a function or technique I can perform on a string to find its source?

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for a string that is found in the rendered content of the site?

Comment: Could the string have been assembled from several strings?

Comment: Find the code that renders the page with this string. Find in this code the relevant section that produces this string ...

Comment: The string is on a contact form being generated from a file outside of the site. It's using Machform to generate the form. If I break machform.php my string (encased in an h2 tag) disappears and I get the php errors. A search of machform.php for the string does not return any results. The problem is the time it takes to find this. Is there some script I can write or tool that will take a single function and output a tree of it's entire inheritance chain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trace where code is coming from (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222160/trace-where-code-is-coming-from-php)