# mysql_num_rows vs. mysql_numrows

Tags: php, mysql

Please redirect me if this question has already been answered.

I have been managing a legacy system, and I have noticed they use the call mysql_numrows instead of mysql_num_rows. I have spent a decent amount of time searching for documentation on these calls, but have turned up nothing. The system works fine, and I have found no evidence of custom functions for this.

Does anyway know whether this is a deprecated function from an older version of PHP? When I am adding to the system I use mysql_num_rows, which as works fine.

Yes I know that mysql_* is outdated and the system should be updated, but that is beyond the scope of my services. I am mainly just curious why this works? Thanks.

Comment: Check to see if they defined their own functions as wrappers

Comment: Maybe you didn't search too long.

Comment: @sircapsalot: "because mysql_numrows is not a function" --- is not a built-in function

Comment: Try this to find out where is it: [How to find out where a function is defined][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222142/how-to-find-out-where-a-function-is-defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysql_numrows() is an alias for mysql_num_rows() used for backward compatibility.

Look at the following documentation - https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows

```
For backward compatibility, the following deprecated alias may be used: mysql_numrows()
```

Hope this helps clarify your question.

I'd suggest using mysql_num_rows() where possible, in case this backward compatibility will be ignored in future versions.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this. This is what I assumed, but didn't notice this note in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

**mysql_numrows** is a deprecated alias for **mysql_num_rows**.

> For backward compatibility, the following deprecated alias may be used: mysql_numrows()

Found it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Answer (score 1):

Thats an alias of mysql_num_rows. 
    <strike>See PHP documentation
    http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.msql-numrows.php</strike>

Comment: That's `msql_`, not `mysql_`.

Comment: Ya that I found that one relatively quickly, but I am using mysql which has been pointed out