# Laravel function helper dd() don't working as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a new project in the last version of Laravel (8.12) and I've figured out that the function helper `dd()` don't work properly.
Supposedly this function halts the execution of the script as is mentioned in the [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd), but in my case, the scripts continues until the end of it.

**Example:**

```
public function store(AnimalNewRequest $request)
{
    dd('Test 1');
    dd('Test 2');
}
```

**Output:**

```
"Test 1"
"Test 2"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"Test 1"
```

Comment: I think the first thing I’d try is to see if you are getting Symfony’s dd function (which is what Laravel uses) or someone else’s: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222404/231316

Comment: Yep, is using the symfony's dd function: `vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php:35`

Comment: I read that FastCGI doesn't respect `exit;` immediately, tho I have not verified, could this be the case?

Comment: Can you temporarily hack your vendor folder's `dump.php` file to put an `echo` before and after the `exit`, just to see it right at that moment?

Comment: @DanielW. Things can go around here, I'm going to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it should be an error of vagrant and laravel homestead. Last update fixed the problem.